# Looking for ctrl zoom functionality

Tags: here-api

I'm using Here Maps, and I was wondering if there was a way to lock the zooming unless I'm <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>mouse wheel</kbd> zooming.

When scrolling through the page, sometimes the mouse is over the map. This makes it so the map accidentally zooms in or out of the map depending on the direction of the mouse wheel scroll. I don't want that to happen!

I know that Google Maps has this functionality. I was wondering if Here Maps has the same functionality as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported by the JavaScript API but an interesting functionality. It is certainly something that we should have on the radar and will add it to the backlog.